# Rails 'rake task' execute in ‘RAILS_ENV=production' with nohup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `rake` task which continuously need to be active. Whenever I ran it by command

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake jobs:abc
```

it works fine but when I close terminal `rake` job get stopped.So I found other solution on it by using `nohup` to run it in background.

I execute command:

```
nohup RAILS_ENV=production rake jobs:work &
```

but it gives error:

> nohup: failed to run command ‘RAILS_ENV=production’: No such file or directory

Please suggest, to way execute `rake` task in a production environment.

Comment: it might be a problem with the environment please crosscheck in the environment folder of config is the any production.rb present or not?

Comment: production.rb present in /config/environments/ directory. " No such file or directory" occurs due to 'nohup' command

Comment: did you try this nohup rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: Hey thanks, it's working fine.

Comment: approve my answer below if agree

Answer (score 11):

Set the environment variable before the `nohup` command.

```
RAILS_ENV=production nohup rake jobs:work
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
  nohup rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=production
```

I have commented the solution above as well

Answer (score 4):

If you need `nohup` functionality, you should also consider [screen](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen).

```
RAILS_ENV=production screen -L rake jobs:work
```

It starts a new terminal which isn't bound to your current session.

To come back to your normal terminal, type `Ctrl+a` and then `d`. You can now log out safely without terminating the `rake` task.

As a bonus, you automatically get a log file in `screenlog.0`.

You can come back to your rake process by typing :

```
screen -r
```